# Issue with Bind9 and wildcards

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dnsmasq

I set up both bind9 and DNSMASQ servers to forward `public-ubiservices.ubi.com` to my IP address, but client kept failing to connect to it, I checked bind9 logs and found out the client is trying to resolve it as `public-ubiservices.ubi.com.hsd1.fl.comcast.net` and Comcast is being their ISP, so I thought it'd be better if I created a zone to catch `public-ubiservices.ubi.com.*` and forward them to my IP address too, but I couldn't figure it out, and I couldn't find any tutorial about it online, so I'm stuck…

Here's the full log: `10-Sep-2023 21:17:56.593 lame-servers: info: network unreachable resolving 'public-ubiservices.ubi.com.hsd1.fl.comcast.net/A/IN': 2001:558:100a:5:68:87:68:244#53`

My bind9 conf

```
@       IN      SOA     ubi.com. admin.ubi.com. (
                2014030801      ; serial
                1D      ; refresh
                1H      ; retry
                1W      ; expire
                3H )    ; minimum
@       300     NS      ns.ubi.com.
ns      300     IN      A       34.154.0.24
public-ubiservices      300     IN      A       34.154.0.24
```

```
zone "ubi.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/named/zones/public-ubiservices.ubi.com.zone";
    allow-query { any; };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a line that says `$ORIGIN ubi.com` this goes before the line that says "ns ..."